# How to change a context menu items color

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm having trouble changing the color of items on context menu bar to white. The bar appears like this-

[image]

I have an Activity which extends AppCompatActivity. I'm using a Toolbar with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme. The style.xml looks like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/LStyled.ActionMode</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/edit_text_border</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LStyled.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    </style>
```

When I switch to context menu, using the following code, the items color changes from white to black-

```
MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.lead_list_context_menu, menu);
```

I've also tried changing theme to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` which changes ActionBar color to white but this also changes dialog and menu popup background and text color (Which I don't want).

Other problem that I have is, with context menu the status bar color changes to black. How can I set status bar color when context menu is enabled.

Any way I can change the text color and status bar color?

Comment: Can you post your XML layout file please?

Comment: @Aspicas Do you want XML of the toolbar?

Comment: Check my answer. Maybe it help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change theme style on your toolbar inside ur XML layout file:

Try that or maybe it can help to do ur similar code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

To change Tittle color you can do it programatically:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

**UPDATE1**

To change `Popup` background color you can assign color directly on new theme only for that popup, and assign that on `AndroidManifest.xml`, try something like that:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
.............
</application>
```

**UPDATE2**

You can change `statusBar` color again programatically when context menu it's enabled:

Try that:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

If it reports an error on `getWindow()` method, try that:

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();

window.setStatusBarColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

**NOTE**

> You only can change StatusBarColor on Android Lollipop, remember that,
>   on Devices with pre-Lollipop version the `statusBarColor` it's allways
>   Black or soemtimesTransparent

Comment: Thank, this solution worked. But the search dialog that I've on the toolbar gives suggestions in a popup with dark background. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: Thanks Aspicas. Status bar color changes to black when context menu is enabled. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Jaguar check `Update2`

Comment: then...I don't know sorry...,  I going to search about it, if i found something I'll write you again. You can accept that answer and put another question, maybe another users can help you with that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Context menu color change is possible using this:

```
 <style name="LStyled.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/actionmode_textcolor_style</item>
    </style>

<style name="actionmode_textcolor_style" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>
```

You change back button color to white from activity or fragment code when you show context menu:

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

You can also change background color of context menu using this:

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/green</item>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to your describe,
you you had better editor your own style,
and let your style extends Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar or other theme.

Comment: I've already overridden Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar theme. The issue is coming only with context menu